# How does TRANSFORM PIVOT works

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
TRANSFORM NbTest SELECT NbTest
FROM TableTest
WHERE Date=#25/10/2021#
GROUP BY Name
PIVOT Name
```

The above query give as output:

```
Expr1002    T1  T2  T3  T4  T5
2           2               
1               1           
0                   0       
2                       2   
3                            3
```

How can I do to get it on one single line :

```
Expr1002    T1  T2  T3  T4  T5
Result =    2   1   0   2   3
```

Comment: Use the crosstab wizard to get started. You should not both _Group By_ and _Pivot_ `Name`.

Comment: @Gustav Im completly lost with this. Do you have a short example in mind ?

Comment: Did you check the wizard? I use it myself.

Comment: @Gustav yes but I can't Do what I try to do... It seems that I miss understand how it works. I can't have : As Column T1 T2 T3 T4 T and as Row Result.....
PIVOT and GROUP BY with the same field does not work

Comment: Provide sample of raw data in your question.

Comment: Study the docs: [Make summary data easier to read by using a crosstab query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361).

Comment: @Dorian, I tried to construct table and run your query - it errors: "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'NbTest' as part of an aggregate function."

Comment: @June7 I just want to Replace Row By Column and Column By row. 
But Idk how to do it

Comment: Have you tried Arturo suggestion? Again, provide sample raw data if you still need help.

Comment: @June7 Im working on it, I will also edit my post if this doesn't work. thank you give me a couple of minutes please

Answer (score 1):

You should list TableTest, as Gustav indicates, and we can then provide better feedback. With the information you provide, I guess that what you want is:

```
TRANSFORM First(NbTest)
SELECT "Result="
FROM TableTest
WHERE Date=#25/10/2021#
GROUP BY True
PIVOT Name ;
```

Notice that this makes sense if for "Date=#25/10/2021#", and for each distinct value of "Name", you only have one value of "NbTest". If for "Date=#25/10/2021#", and for each distinct value of "Name", you have several values of "NbTest", using "First()" will basically produce a random one: in this case may be you prefer to use "Max()" or "Min()" or some other of the available SQL aggregate functions.